# Given any non-empty sets $A, B$ then $A \cap \left( \left\{ A \right\} \times B \right) = \emptyset$

Tags: set-theory

As it is in the title, I'm trying to prove that $A$ and $\left\{ A \right\} \times B$ are disjoint, but I have no idea how to proceed.

The most I have is that is there is an element $(A, b) $ in $A$ then as $(A, b) = \{\{A\}, \{A,b\} \} $ we have $A \in \{A\} \in (A, b) \in A$ which seems strange but I don't know if contradictory.

Comment: What is the definition of an ordered pair that you are using?

Comment: What axioms are you using? Whether or not this may happen depends on them.

Comment: The definition of ordered pair is as I've stated above, $(x, y) =\{\{x\}, \{x, y\} \} $ and the axioms I'm using are those of ZFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $A \in \{A\} \in (A, b) \in A$ which seems strange but I don't know if contradictory

Assuming we are working with the standard ZF axioms, this is indeed contradictory. One of the standard axioms is the axiom of regularity, which (in one formulation states), that given any non-empty set, there exists an element of that set, which is disjoint from its parent set. Symbolically:

> $\forall x \neq \varnothing$ $\exists y \in x (x \cap y = \varnothing)$

To prove that every element is not a member of itself we apply the axiom to the set $\{A\}$. So, there exists $x \in \{A\}$ such that $x \cap \{A\} = \varnothing$. Of course, given that $\{A\}$ is a singleton, we must have $x = A$. So $A \cap \{A\} = \varnothing$. Which is to say that if $y \in \{A\}$ then $y \notin A$. Of course, $\{A\}$ is again a singleton, and the only element this would apply to is $A$ itself. Putting it together, we see that $A \notin A$, and you have your contradiction.

edit: I realize that this isn't actually a contradiction, as you have a chain of 3 inclusions, not just one. However, the idea is the same, and this technique can be extended to show that there is no chain of inclusions which begin and end with the same set.